# A problem in fractions from a very old arithmetic textbook

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

Similar in vein to a problem I posted before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/498991/32441), I would be interested if anyone can give me any pointers as to how one might solve this question from the same arithmetic textbook:

"Simplify

$$\frac{23401369863013698630136986301369629}{34500729927007299270072992700729582}"$$

It is important to note that the book was originally published in 1947, well before any electronic calculation aids were available in schools, so there must be a method which can be carried out on pencil and paper without a ridiculous amount of effort (and paper).

I have tried looking for ways of spotting some pretty large common factors of the numerator and denominator which could be easily cancelled, but without success. There ought to be some cunning way to do this which makes use of the "almost periodic" nature of the digits in both numbers, but I have failed to see it.

Note: the simplified answer has just 7 digits in the numerator and denominator.

Comment: I would guess that the calculation for $\gcd$ of your two numbers is unusually clean and brief; and that the  $\gcd$ is huge. The latter is something we already know, given the nature of the answer.

Comment: calculating the gcd vy repeated subtraction should be feasible

Comment: Yes, I had thought of that - but wouldn't you then have to carry out an enormous long division process on both numbers?

Comment: The gcd is $9999000099990000999900009999$. Maybe you can find it by looking at the numbers?

Comment: @Listing Thanks - that looks like the beginning of a clever trick - I will have a think ...

Comment: Yes, it follows from $1369863-234=1369629$ (last digits of the numerator), same for $729927-345=729582$.

Comment: Do the long division as in polynomial long division, with the "variable" being $10^4$ raised to the power $k$, and coefficients of $9999$. Note that multiplying $9999$ by any other 4 digit unit won't be large enough to throw the subsequent result "past the zeros".

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks! I think I can now turn that into a complete solution, but I will wait to see if anyone else wants to post an answer first

Comment: Wait a minute. I was born in 1956, to commemorate one of the last "Subway Series." Were you born in 1947? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1956_World_Series  and  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subway_Series

Comment: @WillJagy Nope, I was born in 1952, but I found the book in the library at one of the first places I taught - I withdrew it (but kept it for my own amusement) since much of referred to obsolete units such as poles, chains, scruples, grains and drachms.

Comment: So, why were you born in that year? I know why my parents picked 1956. He was at Columbia U., she was at Barnard, it all made sense.

Comment: Aww, I see that I was missing all the fun while working on the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The repeating block in the numerator is $01369863$; the last block, $01369629$, is defective by exactly $234$, the first three digits. The same thing happens in the denominator: the repeating block is $00729927$, and the last block, $00729582$, is defective by $345$, the leading three digits. Let $a=01369863$, $b=00729927$, and $x=10^8$; then the fraction is

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{234x^4+a(x^3+x^2+x+1)-234}{345x^4+b(x^3+x^2+x+1)-345}&=\frac{234+\frac{a}{x-1}}{345+\frac{b}{x-1}}\cdot\frac{x^4-1}{x^4-1}\\\\
&=\frac{234(x-1)+a}{345(x-1)+b}\\\\
&=\frac{234\cdot99999999+1369863}{345\cdot99999999+729927}\\\\
&=\frac{23400000000-234+1369863}{34500000000-345+729927}\\\\
&=\frac{23401369629}{34500729582}\\\\
&=\frac{2600152181}{3833414398}\\\\
&=\frac{236377471}{348492218}\;,
\end{align*}$$

Still not quite down to six digits, but better; the last two steps took out factors of $9$ and $11$, which are recognizable by elementary tests. Knowing that it can be further simplified, I *might* think of testing for divisibility by $101$: $71-74+37-36+2=0$ and similarly in the denominator. That reduces it finally to

$$\frac{2,340,371}{3,450,418}\;.$$

(In fact I got that *ex post facto* from Old John’s comment.)

Comment: Very neat! Not quite the simplest form, though - I get a bit more cancellation to give $2340371/3450418$. The is an interesting connection between the last 3 digits of $2340371$ and $3450418$ compared with those of the original numerators and denominators ...

Comment: Shouldn't the end of your first line be $\dfrac{x^4-1}{x^4-1}$ and not $\dfrac{x^8-1}{x^8-1}$?

Comment: @Ivan: Yep. I originally had $x=10^4$ and didn’t change everything. Thanks.

Comment: Well done indeed - and despite the fact that I can't count - there are 7 not 6 digits in the final numerators and denominators. I blame it on my eyesight after too much hill-walking.

Answer (score 1):

Evidently the gcd is a long calculation by hand, and prone to error in any case. So, trickery it is. Does it  say anything relevant in the text?

```
Tue Nov 26 13:37:03 PST 2013
GCD ( 34500729927007299270072992700729582, 23401369863013698630136986301369629 ) 
 quotient 1
GCD ( 23401369863013698630136986301369629, 11099360063993600639936006399359953 ) 

 quotient 2
GCD ( 11099360063993600639936006399359953, 1202649735026497350264973502649723 ) 

 quotient 9
GCD ( 1202649735026497350264973502649723, 275512448755124487551244875512446 ) 

 quotient 4
GCD ( 275512448755124487551244875512446, 100599940005999400059994000599939 ) 

 quotient 2
GCD ( 100599940005999400059994000599939, 74312568743125687431256874312568 ) 

 quotient 1
GCD ( 74312568743125687431256874312568, 26287371262873712628737126287371 ) 

 quotient 2
GCD ( 26287371262873712628737126287371, 21737826217378262173782621737826 ) 

 quotient 1
GCD ( 21737826217378262173782621737826, 4549545045495450454954504549545 ) 

 quotient 4
GCD ( 4549545045495450454954504549545, 3539646035396460353964603539646 ) 

 quotient 1
GCD ( 3539646035396460353964603539646, 1009899010098990100989901009899 ) 

 quotient 3
GCD ( 1009899010098990100989901009899, 509949005099490050994900509949 ) 

 quotient 1
GCD ( 509949005099490050994900509949, 499950004999500049995000499950 ) 

 quotient 1
GCD ( 499950004999500049995000499950, 9999000099990000999900009999 ) 

 quotient 50
GCD ( 9999000099990000999900009999, 0 ) 

Tue Nov 26 13:37:03 PST 2013
```

Comment: There are no hints or other clues in the textbook, as the problem was in the section labelled "Harder Problems" at the back of the book, so there is presumably something somewhere in the earlier part of the book which gives a clue, but I haven't got the patience to read all 456 pages of the ancient tome, unfortunately.

Comment: @OldJohn But you can walk up and down hills for ten hours. Where is your sense of discipline? Evidently Basel-Chelsea is over, probably also Arsenal-someone.

Comment: Only five hours today - but covered 10 miles. Man Utd tomorrow is more important in this part of the world :)

Comment: @OldJohn, right tomorrow is United- Leverkusen, City - Victoria Plzen. Barcelona tripped up today.